# ServiceStack Razor behaviour when path doesn't exist

Tags: razor, servicestack

I have these settings:

```
    CustomHttpHandlers = {
        {HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/notfound")},
        {HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new RazorHandler("/unauthorized")},
    }
```

When I visit something inside a `/stars` folder that doesn't exist:

`/stars/asdf/xyz`

It first checks for `/stars/asdf/default.cshtml`. Then goes to `stars/default.cshtml` and loads whichever level that has `default` page. So, only if `/stars` root folder doesn't exist at all, then `/notfound` would be loaded.

Is it possible to ask it to load `/notfound` when `/asdf/xyz` doesn't exist?

This is the behaviour under root directory:

`http://localhost:2000/asdf` will take you to `/notfound`. However, it doesn't do so under folders.

Tnank you.

EDIT ------------------------------------------------------

I noticed actually if I go to bad url `/stars/asdf` where `/stars` doesn't have a default but root `/default.cshtml` actually exists, in that case, both `/notfound` -> `/default` are loaded up one after other?!?

My settings are wrong? SS glitched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's routing priority, is as follows. ServiceStack calls `ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler` to get the handler for the current route.

`ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler` returns:

1. A matching RawHttpHandler, if any.
2. If the domain root, the handler returned by  `GetCatchAllHandlerIfAny(...),` if any.
3. If the route matches a metadata uri, the relevant handler, if any.
4. The handler returned by `ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandlerForPathInfo` if any.
5. NotFoundHandler.

`ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandlerForPathInfo` returns:

1. If the url matches a valid REST route, a new RestHandler.
2. If the url matches an existing file or directory, it returns

   - the handler returned by  `GetCatchAllHandlerIfAny(...),` if any.
   - If it's a supported filetype, a StaticFileHandler,
   - If it's not a supported filetype, the ForbiddenHttpHandler.
3. The handler returned by `GetCatchAllHandlerIfAny(...),` if any.
4. null.

The CatchAllHandlers array contains functions that evaluate the url and either return a handler, or null. The functions in the array are called in sequence and the first one that doesn't return null handles the route.

The code that controls whether the default file is served is part of the StaticFileHandler.  It's only called for existing files and directories.

Here's the relevent fragement:

```
foreach (var defaultDoc in EndpointHost.Config.DefaultDocuments)
{
    var defaultFileName = Path.Combine(fi.FullName, defaultDoc);
    if (!File.Exists(defaultFileName)) continue;
    r.Redirect(request.GetPathUrl() + '/' + defaultDoc);
    return;
}
```

As you can see, if the default file isn't found at the requested directory, it redirects up the directory chain until it finds a default file to serve.  If you need to change this behavior, you can override it by adding a CatchAllHander you code.  More details about writing a CatchAllHandler can be found in my answer to a related question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618851/149060